# How to get the difference of two numbers (standard deviation)?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I have many pairs like:

```
A  B
10 20
15.3 19.5
23 13
45 32
```

etc etc, 
I create those pairs calculating the standard deviation of many vectors (R vectors) and then group them by 2(A - B).

Now, I have to filter those pairs by their percentage difference.
I set a percentage like `30%` then I filter all the pairs to get those who have a difference **BELOW** or **EQUAL** 30%

My question is, is this formula correct to get the difference (in % of two numbers)

```
((A / B) -1) * 100
```

My doubt is that I need their difference to understand if i can take them or not but if I do: ((B / A) -1) *100 obviously I get a different result, example:

```
A = 10
B = 20
A-B % = -50 %  ((10 / 20) -1) *100
B-A % = 100 %  ((20 / 10) -1) *100
```

So, How can I better study the real difference of two numbers(standard deviation difference)?

**EDIT (@Henry)**

```
> a <- log(sd(rnorm(250)))
> b <- log(sd(rnorm(250)))
> a/b
[1] 0.6049963
```

**0.60%** of change ?

Thank you!

Comment: Ignoring issues about where the numbers came from and what they mean, would $(A-B)/[(A+B)/2]$, the difference divided by the average, (or $|A-B|/[(A+B)/2]$, or even $|A-B|/(A+B)$ -- $A$ and $B$ are within $x\%$ of their average value) be a better measure of the "percentage difference"?

Comment: @DilipSarwate yes should be a better measure BUT i need a value to check if this difference is above or not...if i dont have the percentage how can i compare them?

Comment: @DilipSarwate what do you mean with "are within x% of their average value?

Comment: If $A=10$, $B=30$, then each differs from the average value $20$ by $10$, which is $$10/20=0.5=0.5\times\frac{100}{100}=\frac{50}{100}=50\%$$ of the average value. _Percent_ means per $100$. If $A=18,B=22$, the average is still $20$ but now $A$ and $B$ differ from their average by just $10\%$ and so we can say that $A$ and $B$ both are **within** $11\%$, or $10.1\%$, or (slightly incorrectly) $10\%$ of their average value.  In all these cases, the _percentage_ is calculated and stated as $|A-B|/(A+B)\times 100\%$. The _data_ cannot provide "a value to check if this difference is above or not."

Comment: "BUT i need a value to check if this difference is above or not...if i dont have the percentage how can i compare them?"  What value you set as the threshold ($30\%$ or $10\%$ or whatever) is not something that you determine from the data.  This value is determined by _you_, or by your professor, or by the client "I will accept variations of up to $25\%$", and then you have to find which of the data satisfy this externally imposed criterion and which don't.  The data $A=10,B=30$ don't tell you that $25\%$ is the acceptable variation.

Comment: Since you have the tag "standard deviation", note that the $|A-B|/2$ is exactly the standard deviation of the set of two numbers $\{A, B\}$, and $A$ and $B$ both differ from their mean $(A+B)/2$ by _exactly_ one standard deviation.

Comment: @DilipSarwate thank you so much for the explanation, I know that a formula can't say YES is ABOVE or YES is below, obviously this is a number that I use AS input. My goal is to get a number that I can compare with this value, that as you wrote is the "acceptable variation". ok So i can use (A-B)/(A+B) x 100

Answer (score 1):

Excel has an "IF" function.  You could set it up so that if A>B it would calculate the percentage difference using one formula, and if B>A it would  use the other.  the function takes 3 arguments:
1. the "if" argument, as in "A1>B1", where A1 and B1 are each cells.
2. the "if true" argument, where you would insert the formula you'd want to use for the cases where A1>B1.
3. the "if false" argument, where you'd insert the other formula.

Comment: my goal is to understand if that formula is good or not

Answer (score 1):

If all your numbers are positive, then a measure of relative change which is sometimes useful is  $\log_e(A/B) = \log_e(A)-\log_e(B)$.  The advantage of this is that it is symmetric with a change of sign and that two successive changes can be added together.  For small changes it is also close the percentage change.

So for example if you had the numbers 400, 500 and 625: 500 is a 25% increase on  400; 600 is a 20% increase on 500; but 600 is a 50% increase on 400 (not 25%+20%); and 400 is 20% reduction on 500.

Restate this following my suggestion and 500 is about 0.223 up from 400; 625 is about 0.182 up from 500; 625 is about 0.405 up from 400 (0.223+0.182); and 400 is about 0.223 down from 500 (the same magnitude as in the opposite direction but with the sign reversed).

Comment: please take a look at the edit un the question I tried to implement the log() function using R. I calculated the standard deviation of two samples and then calculate the log and divide the results.

Comment: @Dail: Your edit is a little confusing. (a) 0.60 is 60% not 0.60%, but presentationally I personally would not use percentages here. (b) Use `log(A/B)`or `log(A)-log(B)` but not `log(A)/log(B)`.

Comment: Yes I could use LOG() the problem is, how can i set the value(input) to filter the pairs? I mean...I Need a value if the pair difference is ABOVE I remove the pair else I keep it. If I do not use the % what number can i put as limit ?